# How can I inline a javascript file into a html page using gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a javascript file that I would like to uglify and inline in a html page.

I've found a bunch of grunt tasks for inlining css files but none for js.

Comment: You just want minimize a javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this plugin, https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-string-replace . Under the config example it has an example of how to inline a script.